# get highest array value by key php

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, key, highest

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 5 [question_id_count] => 17 ) 
    [1] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 8 [question_id_count] => 15 ) 
    [2] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 9 [question_id_count] => 17 ) 
    [3] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 13 [question_id_count] => 13 ) 
    [4] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 14 [question_id_count] => 9 ) 
    [5] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 15 [question_id_count] => 13 ) 
    [6] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 27 [question_id_count] => 7 ) 
    [7] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 28 [question_id_count] => 2 ) 
    [8] => stdClass Object ( [question_id] => 29 [question_id_count] => 8 ) 
)
```

This is my array, I need the output as: 17 which is the highest value

Comment: got the solution:


$max = null;
foreach ($arr as $item) {
  $max = $max === null ? $item->dnum : max($max, $item->dnum);
}

Comment: Then post it as your own answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<?php
$test = array("1" => "test", "5" => "bla", "3" => "blubb");

echo max(array_keys($test));
?>
```

Next solution is:

```
$maxs = array_keys($array, max($array))

               OR

echo array_search(max($array), $array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `arsort($your_array)`, and then you will get the first value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array( 10 => "AAA", 12 => "212", 17 => "SQW" );
max(array_keys($arr));
```

> Output will be: 17

Comment: Your answer may be good for you. But try to give a brief note on what you've done. This may help someone else.